# Is string functions used in linq queries breaks down into query expressions?

Tags: linq

I have the scenario, where i am using string equals method for comparison with the data in db and it is breaking down into query expressions, so how its working? Do Linq supports all c# methods in the queries or only string class methods.

```
var us = "uttams";
IQueryable<UserData> use = (from user in entity.Users
                            where user.UserName.equals(us)
                            select new UserData{ UserName = user.UserName }).AsQueryable<UserData>();
var name = use.FirstOrDefault().UserName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a set of methods that are supported, and all the others are not supported (you should think about it as a [whitelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist)).

[CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

`Boolean Equals(String a, String b)` method is translated into `=` operator in SQL query.